# Bouncy Castle FIPS mode for PKCS#12 KeyStore Format

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, keystore, pkcs#12

Does Bouncy Castle FIPS support `"PKCS12"` as KeyStore/trustStore? I read somewhere that in the approved mode it doesn't support PKCS#12 format but that it is supported in non approved mode (the generally used libraries).

Comment: Hi Chandra, welcome to SO, nice first question which solicited an answer from a Bouncy Castle dev :). Please do try and write your post as clearly as possible, using full sentences. The title is also really important - make it as specific as possible. Try and have a few more tags, especially mentioning the language / runtime. Otherwise: the more concise the question the better.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [the BC-FJA user guide](https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BC-FJA-UserGuide-1.0.2.pdf), section "7. Key Stores":

> The PKCS12 key store is not available in approved-mode of operation
> due to the algorithms required for PBE key generation in the PKCS#12
> standard.

It is available only to threads that are not running in approved-mode.