# PKCS12 - Bouncy Castle FIPS Mode

Tags: bouncycastle

In FIPS Mode, the PKCS#12 format must use compatible encryption and hashing algorithms when encrypting the file.

As i read the BC -FIPS documentation it says in the approved mode they don't support PKCS#12 so that means we can't read PKCS12 Keystore in BC-FIPS approved mode ; We are using BC-FIPS as the Cryptographic providers and also use PKCS12 and JKS format for storing keys and certs.

BC-FIPS claims -"The PKCS12 key store supports the
following variations:
• PKCS12-3DES-3DES: the default, uses Triple-DES for any encryption task." So can we read PKCS12  using any of this mechanisms and claim that we are FIPS compliant .

Migrating to BCFKS is a big exercise and it might introduce compatibility issues.

-Chandra

Comment: Where is your question please ?

Comment: Oh Essentially want to understand if we can read PKCS12 Key stores in BC-FIPS approval mode.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question "if we can read PKCS12 Key stores in BC-FIPS approval mode" is **NO**.

Four months ago you asked the (nearly) same question here: [Bouncy Castle FIPS mode for PKCS#12 KeyStore Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366284/bouncy-castle-fips-mode-for-pkcs12-keystore-format) and
you got an answer from @Peter Dettmann:

```
Quoting from the BC-FJA user guide, section "7. Key Stores":
The PKCS12 key store is **not available** in approved-mode of operation due to the algorithms required for PBE key generation in the PKCS#12 standard.
It is available only to threads that are not running in approved-mode.
```

Below you find a stripped version of a BC FIPS example ("KeyStr.java") that first runs in disabled approved mode and then I'm enabling the mode -
you will receive an error message:

```
Testing a PKCS12 keystore with BC FIPS in approved mode

running in approved mode: false
PKCS12 (certificate): true
running in approved mode: true
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvIOException: exception decrypting data - java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
...
```

The following code is for educational purpose only and may be **unsecure**.

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v1CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

public class Pkcs12KeystoreFipsApprovedMode
{
     public static byte[] storeCertificatePkcs12(char[] storePassword, X509Certificate trustedCert)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BCFIPS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("trustedca", trustedCert);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        keyStore.store(bOut, storePassword);
        return bOut.toByteArray();
    }

    private static KeyStore rebuildStore(String storeType, char[] storePassword, byte[] encoding)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType, "BCFIPS");
        keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(encoding), storePassword);
        return keyStore;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, OperatorCreationException, PKCSException, IOException
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());
        System.out.println("Testing a PKCS12 keystore with BC FIPS in approved mode\n");
        System.out.println("running in approved mode: " + org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode());
        KeyPair caKeyPair = generateKeyPair();
        X509Certificate caCert = makeV1Certificate(caKeyPair.getPrivate(), caKeyPair.getPublic());

        char[] storePass = "storePassword".toCharArray();
        System.out.println("PKCS12 (certificate): " + rebuildStore("PKCS12", storePass, storeCertificatePkcs12(storePass, caCert)).isCertificateEntry("trustedca"));

        // running now in approved mode
        org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.setApprovedOnlyMode(true);
        System.out.println("running in approved mode: " + org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode());
        System.out.println("PKCS12 (certificate): " + rebuildStore("PKCS12", storePass, storeCertificatePkcs12(storePass, caCert)).isCertificateEntry("trustedca2"));
    }
    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BCFIPS");
        keyPair.initialize(384);
        return keyPair.generateKeyPair();
    }

    public static X509Certificate makeV1Certificate(PrivateKey caSignerKey, PublicKey caPublicKey)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, OperatorCreationException {
        long THIRTY_DAYS = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        X509v1CertificateBuilder v1CertBldr = new JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder(
                new X500Name("CN=Issuer CA"),
                BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 5),
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + THIRTY_DAYS),
                new X500Name("CN=Issuer CA"),
                caPublicKey);
        JcaContentSignerBuilder signerBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA384withECDSA").setProvider("BCFIPS");
        return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BCFIPS").getCertificate(v1CertBldr.build(signerBuilder.build(caSignerKey)));
    }
}
```